# JavaFX Centering VBox inside GridPane

Tags: java, javafx

would really appreciate some help with my problem.

I'm using JavaFX and the NetBeans IDE.

I am making a very simple launch window for a desktop client.
The window currently looks like this image.

Current Look:

[image: current look]

Wanted Look (editted with paint):

[image: wanted look]

In other words, I want the buttons to be:

1. centered underneath the 'Welcome' text
2. maintain their current width

My current setup is:

I have a GridPane acting as the root. Not sure why JavaFX chose to use (col,row), but that's how I'll represent my setup in the following:

- @GridPane(0,0) -> 'Welcome' Text
- @GridPane(0,1) -> VBox (this VBox contains the 2 buttons shown in above image)

The relevant code (or what I think is relevant, please correct me if I am wrong) is below:

```
//adds GridPane to Scene
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
row1.setPercentHeight(25);
grid.getRowConstraints().add(row1);
grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 400, 300,Color.WHITESMOKE);

//Create welcome message and add it to grid, and align it to the center
Text sceneTitle = new Text("Welcome");
grid.add(sceneTitle,0,0);
GridPane.setHalignment(sceneTitle,HPos.CENTER);

//Create buttons and fix their widths
Button newBtn = new Button("Create New Project");
Button loadBtn = new Button("Load Existing Project");
newBtn.setMaxWidth(150);
loadBtn.setMaxWidth(150);

//Create a VBox, add children to it, and then add it to the grid
VBox vBtns = new VBox();
vBtns.setSpacing(5);
vBtns.getChildren().addAll(newBtn,loadBtn);
grid.add(vBtns,0,1);
```

I've tried a lot of different things.. to mention some of the more 'logical' ones:

```
//1. Center the VBox within its current GridPane cell
GridPane.setHalignment(vBtns,HPos.CENTER);

//2. Center the buttons within the VBox 
newBtn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
loadBtn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

I've never been good at GUI programming. It's very discouraging when something that should be so simple takes so long to figure out.
Are there any developers out there who can help me find a solution?

Comment: don't try to fight it in the GridPane. Instead, wrap your stuff in yet another VBox, make that 100% width, and make it's contents centered. Then your inner contents will be in the center of that VBox. JavaFX/FXML is all about nesting elements in other elements to get the style you desire. (also, you should really check out FXML instead of hand coding this gui, JavaFX really benefits from FXML, and you can then use SceneBuilder to Drag-n-Drop your GUI elements and get them all lined up, etc..).

Comment: Or, just put all three things in a single `VBox`. Or a single `GridPane`. But there's no obvious need for two layout panes here at all.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Hi! Yeah I have the Scene Builder plugin installed.. I wasn't happy with how nested elements weren't centering the way I wanted them to so I went back to code.

Comment: @HenryLin Using FXML instead of hand-coding all of your UI will make things a bit more "manageable", although there is obviously a learning curve. SceneBuilder can do everything you can do with code, so if it wasn't working the way you wanted, it's probably because you didn't checkbox the right option or something. It's definitely worth learning, and will save you considerable time down the road.

Comment: @James_D I tried putting them all into one VBox earlier, but I switched back to a GridPane because I want to add a small icon to be displayed to the left of 'Welcome' text. Unfortunately I had to take it out because I couldn't get the text to center properly with the ImageView included.

Comment: Use a `Label` instead of `Text` and set the graphic on the label for your icon...?

Comment: @James_D Yeah, the Label worked. Thanks for your help and sorry for the dumb questions. I promise I did read the Label documentation earlier, but I thought it would superimpose the text overtop the graphic. I guess I should have looked up an example. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: The `contentDisplay` property controls the relation between the text and the graphic. Setting it to `CENTER` will superimpose; other settings will position the graphic relative to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it with your current setup, you just need:

```
vBtns.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

However, this just seems overly complex. Why not just do

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LayoutTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
        row1.setPercentHeight(25);
        grid.getRowConstraints().add(row1);

        ColumnConstraints colConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
        colConstraints.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(colConstraints);

        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 400, 300,Color.WHITESMOKE);

        //Create welcome message and add it to grid, and align it to the center
        Text sceneTitle = new Text("Welcome");
        sceneTitle.setStyle("-fx-font-size:48;");
        grid.add(sceneTitle,0,0);

        //Create buttons and fix their widths
        Button newBtn = new Button("Create New Project");
        Button loadBtn = new Button("Load Existing Project");
        newBtn.setMaxWidth(150);
        loadBtn.setMaxWidth(150);

        grid.add(newBtn, 0, 1);

        GridPane.setMargin(loadBtn, new Insets(5, 0, 5, 0));
        grid.add(loadBtn, 0, 2);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrap the buttons into a VBox because I want to specify a gap between the two of them only.
I initially tried to do what you're suggesting but the buttons were sticking together and specifying a "grid.setVgap" would not work because it would place an ugly space between the text and the buttons.

Comment: You can do `GridPane.setMargin(node, insets)` to more precisely control the amount of space on any side of any node in the grid; or you can use row constraints to give even more control over the relative heights of each row, and the positioning of the content of the cells.

Comment: since stackoverflow doesnt allow private messages and you seem to be one of most active JavaFX stackoverflow responders. I was hoping I could ask you a question from here: Do you personally manually write the code, edit FXML or use scene builder? I wrote the code manually for that silly page in this post and now I am trying to reproduce it using scene builder. Did you follow a similar process when you first started learning this framework?

Comment: I learned by doing it "manually' in Java code; I find the code-completion from Eclipse better at showing me all the options than finding the relevant control in a GUI builder. But then I am old-school (or perhaps just old). For actual development now, mostly FXML, some by hand, some layouts I will build in SceneBuilder (and sometimes I need to subsequently edit for features SceneBuilder does not support).